# Javascript window with passback parameters after close

Tags: javascript

How can I pass back some arguments from a window that is closed?

For example [Insert file](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/examples/full.php) dialog in TinyMCE does this. When file is selected the url is pasted into editor. (The url is passed back to the main window)

I am using Prototype fyi, if that helps.

PS: I rephrased this question to better describe my requirements [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093313/make-onclick-event-stick-after-page-reload).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use window.open('myPage.htm') to launch your popup.

Then within myPage.htm you can use [opener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.opener) to reference the parent window before closing...

```
opener.document.getElementById('yourDiv').innerHTML = 'Look at me!';
self.close();
```

Comment: You betcha!  I just updated my answer, added a link for reference.