# Make onclick event stick after page reload

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have Javascript that opens another window and registers a click handler for all the links:

```
//Inside a class somewhere
this.file_browser_window = $(window.open("/filebrowser", "file_browser_window",
        "width=800,height=600"))

Event.observe(this.file_browser_window, 'load', function (){
     //This is the event I am after
     Event.observe(this.file_browser_window, 'click', handle_click_in_browser);
}.bindAsEventListener(this));

// The Handler function
function handle_click_in_browser(evt){
   evt.stop();  

   url = evt.target.href;

   if(url && url.endsWith('.png')){
       console.log("Image clicked");
       //REMMEMBER THIS URL ON MAIN PAGE
       this.close();
   }
   else{
       console.log("Regular stuff clicked", this);
       this.location = url; //<-- THIS is the breaking point
   }
}
```

However, when the user clicks on some link in that popup window, when the page reloads, my CLICK handlers are gone!

The links in the popup window point to the same domain.

Now, I **cannot alter the source(html) on the popup window**. I need to **catch** the href of the link-tag (if it points to image) that the user clicked on.

I am running [django-filebrowser](http://code.google.com/p/django-filebrowser/) in the popup window if anyone is interested.

Comment: Do the links in the popup window point to pages in the same domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be applying your click event handlers for the popup page, within the popup page itself.  I don't see any reason to make the parent window responsible for these event handlers.

Comment: Because I am using an pre-made filebrowser for my popup. It does all the stuff on it's own, I just need to capture the result. I update the question with the link to it.

Comment: So as a workaround, could you popup a custom page with your event binding code in it, but have the filebrowser part load in an iframe on that custom page?  The event binding code could look at the document inside the iframe and attached the listeners every time the iframe reloads.

Comment: Um.. i could do that. Would be great you could present it as an answer.

Comment: It's pre-made, but why can't you modify it to include one simple javascript file?

Comment: And you say it does all the stuff on it's own, which is clearly untrue, otherwise you wouldn't have to write this code to begin with.

Comment: I cannot modify it to add one simple js file because it can change in the future (by the author) and I would not know which changes where mine and which were not mine. Regarding it doing stuff - it does stuff like create folders, upload images etc, stuff that is not related to the functionality i am looking for in this case.

Comment: Well, I would never dare put myself in that position, so I can't help you any further!

Comment: Lol, it doesn't depend on me. Mr. Never Dare phtttt!

Comment: Ok, this is what I did in the end: I changed the source of the popup window. It's a flaw on the django-filebrowser's part that they don't include any callbacks.

Comment: You changed the source of the popup?!  :-O  I thought that was *impossible*

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to work around the issue by putting your filebrowser page inside an iframe on in a new popup window.  I may come back to edit this code, but for now here is some code that might get you started (probably will not work as-is -- doing this without testing)

== Page you're launching the popup from ===========

```
// some code to launch the file browser wrapper popup
var file_browser_popup = $(window.open("/new_wrapper_page.html", "file_browser_popup",
                "width=800,height=600"));
```

== Inside `new_wrapper_page.html` ===========

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
// most of your existing code stays the same, but things are moved around

function listenForClicks() {
    var ifrm = $('filebrowser_iframe');
    var content = (ifrm.contentWindow ? ifrm.contentWindow.document : (ifrm.contentDocument ? ifrm.contentDocument : null));
    if (content) {
        //This is the event I am after
        Event.observe(content, 'click', handle_click_in_browser);
    }

}

// The Handler function
function handle_click_in_browser(evt){
   evt.stop();  

   url = evt.target.href;

   if(url && url.endsWith('.png')){
       console.log("Image clicked");
       //REMEMBER THIS URL ON MAIN PAGE
       parent.close();
   }
   else{
       console.log("Regular stuff clicked", this);
       parent.location = url; //<-- THIS is the breaking point
   }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="filebrowser_iframe" src="/filebrowser/" width="800" height="600" onload="listenForClicks();"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyway, it's something to play with.  Let me know if you need more direction -- my Prototype skills are weak and I'm only using your existing code to figure out what exactly you're trying to do...

Comment: what happends when the content in iframe changes? Would the click get re-registered or do I need to do it manually?

Comment: How do I keep iframe on the page when I click a link inside the browser? Some like: iframe.contentWindow.location = url OR iframe.content = load_from_url(url)...???

Comment: OK. so this works: $('filebrowser_iframe').src = url; BUT what about form posts? They no longer work with this, and I cannot let them go through normally since they will get rid of my iframe.

Comment: Damn, i just thought of file uploads they cannot be handled with ajax

Comment: Does django have documentation on how you're supposed to use this control?

Comment: No, it's not django supported. It's independent. But this has little to do with django, just me trying to wrap my head around how to use this type of interaction between windows/frames etc.

Comment: Ok, thanks but this didn't work for various reasons, including the uploads etc.. Thanks for the idea though, I ultimately went with changing the source of the popup.